# Having troubles connecting my EMR Hive cluster to external metastore which is AWS MYSQL RDS

Tags: hive, emr

I have an EMR Hive cluster and I am trying to connect it to the external metastore which is AWS MYSQL RDS.

Here is my hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://meredith.cckyyg5sffpl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
  <property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hive</value>
<description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
 <property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>meredith</value>
<description>Password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
<property>
</configuration>
```

I am able to start the hive from cli but its not using the external metastore instead its using the local mysql server.

I am also attaching the hive metastore log which is trying to connect to the local mysql metastore.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What EMR release version are you using and how are you installing the hive-site.xml?

Comment: I am using EMR 4.1.0 and I changing the hive-site.xml manually as the bootstrap actions and edit software configuration are failing to do.

Comment: Here's an example short-hand json configuration for EMR 4.1.0 using the console:

[{"classification":"hive-site", "properties":{"javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName":"dbusername", "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword":"dbpassword", "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL":"jdbc:mysql://host.fqdn.tld:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"}, "configurations":[]}]

Comment: I tried the following but the cluster gets terminated with errors when doing so.Here is the cluster Id j-28OSVVYTGFC2M.

Comment: That cluster has defined the field "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName".  Just drop that from the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Chris.I removed the following property but the cluster failed at the bootstrap itself and here is the cluster ID j-MF0HZXV9HEKL.The following configuration is used [{"classification":"hive-site","properties":{"javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName":"root","javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword":"hivetest","javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL":"jdbc:mysql://hive.cckyyg5sffpl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"}}]

Comment: I am contacting you externally through the AWS support case system to discuss further.  We can post results here once done with investigation.

Comment: @ChristopherB was this resolved? I am getting a similar issue. tx

Comment: Could you please update on this? I am getting same error. Thanks in advance